# How to remove a number among a string column in dataframe in scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am reading a text file in scala and I have the following row:

```
05:49:56.604899 00:00:00:00:00:02 > 00:00:00:00:00:03, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 10202: 10.0.0.2.54880 > 10.0.0.3.5001: Flags [.], seq 3641977583:3641987719, ack 129899328, win 58, options [nop,nop,TS val 432623 ecr 432619], length 10136
```

I used this code to extract a pattern:

```
+---------------+--------------+--------------+-----+-----+
|   time_stamp_0|   sender_ip_1| receiver_ip_2|label|count|
+---------------+--------------+--------------+-----+-----+
|05:49:56.604899|10.0.0.2.54880| 10.0.0.3.5001|    1|   19|
```

Here is my code:

```
val customSchema = StructType(Array(
      StructField("time_stamp_0", StringType, true),
      StructField("sender_ip_1", StringType, true),
      StructField("receiver_ip_2", StringType, true),
      StructField("label", IntegerType, true)))

    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////make train dataframe
    val Dstream_Train = sc.textFile("/Users/saeedtkh/Desktop/sharedsaeed/Test/trace1.txt")
    val Row_Dstream_Train = Dstream_Train.map(line => line.split(">")).map(array => {
      val first = Try(array(0).trim.split(" ")(0)) getOrElse ""
      val second = Try(array(1).trim.split("")(6)) getOrElse ""
      val third = Try(array(2).trim.split(" ")(0).replace(":", "")) getOrElse ""
      Row.fromSeq(Seq(first, second, third, 1))
    })
    val Frist_Dataframe = session.createDataFrame(Row_Dstream_Train, customSchema).toDF("time_stamp_0", "sender_ip_1", "receiver_ip_2", "label")
    val columns1and2 = Window.partitionBy("sender_ip_1", "receiver_ip_2") // <-- matches groupBy
```

My problem is I need to extract  the sender_ip_1 and receiver_ip_2 columns like this:

```
   +---------------+--------------+--------------+-----+-----+
    |   time_stamp_0|   sender_ip_1| receiver_ip_2|label|count|
    +---------------+--------------+--------------+-----+-----+
    |05:49:56.604899|10.0.0.2      |    10.0.0.3  |    1|   19|
```

It means that I need to omit the last number of IP. (The number is not constant and it is variable)

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest possible way to do this in your example is to remove that dangling port number in your lambdas by doing something like the following (output of a Scala shell):

```
scala> val stringToTrim = "255.255.255.255.1"
stringToTrim: String = 255.255.255.255.1

scala> stringToTrim.take(stringToString.lastIndexOf("."))
res8: String = 255.255.255.255
```

In you case for example you would replace `first` and `third` in your row as follows:

```
val firstFixed = first.take(first.lastIndexOf("."))
val thirdFixed = third.take(third.lastIndexOf("."))
Row.fromSeq(Seq(firstFixed, second, thirdFixed, 1))
```

Answer (score 0):

I would simply use regex, it is a lot cleaner in my opionion:

```
val regex = """^(\d\d:\d\d:\d\d.\d+).+length \d+: (\d{1,4}\.\d{1,4}\.\d{1,4}\.\d{1,4})\.\d+ > (\d{1,4}\.\d{1,4}\.\d{1,4}\.\d{1,4}).\d+.+""".r

val customSchema = StructType(Array(
  StructField("time_stamp_0", StringType, nullable = true),
  StructField("sender_ip_1", StringType, nullable = true),
  StructField("receiver_ip_2", StringType, nullable = true),
  StructField("label", IntegerType, nullable = true)))

val line = "05:49:56.604899 00:00:00:00:00:02 > 00:00:00:00:00:03, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 10202: 10.0.0.2.54880 > 10.0.0.3.5001: Flags [.], seq 3641977583:3641987719, ack 129899328, win 58, options [nop,nop,TS val 432623 ecr 432619], length 10136"

val rdd = spark.sparkContext
  .parallelize(Seq(line))
  .map({
    case regex(timestamp, senderIp, receiverIp) =>
      Row(timestamp, senderIp, receiverIp, 1)
    case x => // Do something else here?
      throw new RuntimeException(s"Invalid line: $x")
  })

spark
  .createDataFrame(rdd, customSchema)
  .toDF("time_stamp_0", "sender_ip_1", "receiver_ip_2", "label")
  .show()
```